# Shrubs leaves are yellow/brown - Butterfly bush, crape myrtle

Tags: trees

We have several shrubs/bushes around our house (front back left and right) and they all have this same common issue. Any idea what it is and how to correct it?

For these specific bushes, last summer we pulled out several adult shrubs of this flower bed and refilled the holes with new dirt. When giving away the shrubs, a lady who works at a local nursery said "I don't want these ones. They're sick" to shrubs which had this same yellow leaf.

[image: bf2]
[image: bf1]
[image: leaf2]
[image: leaf1]

Answer (score 1):

This is a butterfly bush or *Buddleia*. And it is not sick, but also not doing particularly well since it has so few flowers. The yellow leaves are just normal dying off of leaves that have done their job and will go to compost at the base of the bush. It probably just needs a good pruning to restore flowering, it is a very forgiving genus.